# if x belongs to keywords the AI will automatically answer

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

i am coding the AI with python but i have a problem
I want it to print out the answer if the question has keywords of KeyS
the error when running is in the line:

```
if you == KeyS:
    robot = 'hi friend'
```

i have tried this code:

```
import time
import pyttsx3

day = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
KeyS = 'hi', 'hello'

loop = True
while loop:
    you = input('you:')
    if you == KeyS:
        robot = 'hi friend'
    elif you == 'time':
        robot = day
    elif you == 'bye':
        robot = 'bye sir'
        print('robot:' + robot)
        robotsay = pyttsx3.init()
        robotsay.say(robot)
        robotsay.runAndWait()
        exit()
    else:
        robot = 'i do not understand'
    print('robot:' + robot)
    robotsay = pyttsx3.init()
    robotsay.say(robot)
    robotsay.runAndWait()
```

my english is not good.so please forgive me if there is any grammar mistake

Comment: What input did you give? Did you give either of 'hi' or 'hello' or did u give 'hi, hello' as a whole?

Comment: i have given 'hi', 'hello' as a whole

Comment: This line `KeyS = 'hi, 'hello'` is a syntax error. The opening and closing quotes do not match.

Comment: i have fix it to KeyS= 'hi', 'hello'
but it still have error while running

Comment: `KeyS= 'hi', 'hello'` turns it into a tuple of 2 strings. Think about what you actually need. Do you need 1 string with "hi" and "hello" (`"'hi', 'hello'"` or `"hi, hello"`)? Or do you need a tuple of 2 strings (`'hi', 'hello'`)? The way you will compare the input to the keys depends on which structure you use for the inputs and the keys (string comparison or check for string in tuple of strings).

Comment: i need  a tuple of 2 strings('hi', 'hello')
i want robot to print out the answer if the question has any words of KeyS.How i can do it?
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
  if you == KeyS:
        robot = 'hi friend'
```

to

```
  if you in KeyS:
        robot = 'hi friend'
```

Since KeyS is a tuple of strings.